# Why are both constructors called in my program?

Tags: c++

I want to create an object of class `MyClass` and pass it to the constructor of class `Foo`.
What's weird is, that from the class `MyClass` both constructors are called.
What am I missing here? I am not creating a second object of `MyCalss`, am I?

This is a snippet of my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyClass oMyClass("string");

    Foo oFoo(oMyClass);
}   



/*MyClass.h*/
MyClass::MyClass()
{
  printf("constructor() called\n");
}

MyClass::MyClass(std::string myString)
{
  printf("constructor(std::string) called\n");
}


/*Foo.h*/

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo( MyClass& oMyClass);
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
private:
    MyClass m_oMyClass;
};

/*Foo.cpp*/
Foo::Foo( MyClass& oMyClass)
{
  m_oMyClass = oMyClass;
}

Foo::Foo()
{
}
```

Comment: I bet your `Foo` class isn't initialising its `MyClass` member properly. Show us `Foo`.

Comment: In particular, I'll be that it doesn't initialize its MyClass member in the initializer list, and instead relies on assignment in the ctor body. Agree with need for code.

Comment: What do you mean "both constructor are called"? I to not see `MyClass(std::string)` being called anywhere here.

Comment: @AdamBurry Third line?

Comment: @JosephMansfield Oops. Time for stimulants. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You need to initialise the `MyClass` member of `Foo` in a member initialization list, otherwise it will be default initialized first (before your assignment):

```
Foo::Foo(MyClass& oMyClass)
  : m_oMyClass(omyClass)
{ }
```

Comment: isn't an initializer list the same as `m_oMyClass = oMyClass` ?

Comment: @tzippy No, that's an assignment. The member will have been initialized when the constructor began, and then you assign to it.

Comment: Thanks, that helped though! Now I need to implement the copyconstructor, because I have a segfault...

Answer (score 1):

In this statement in main

```
MyClass oMyClass("string");
```

there is obviously called constructor

```
MyClass::MyClass(std::string myString)
{
  printf("constructor(std::string) called\n");
}
```

In this statement in main

```
Foo oFoo(oMyClass);
```

there is called constructor

```
Foo::Foo( MyClass& oMyClass)
{
  m_oMyClass = oMyClass;
}
```

As class Foo is defined such a way that it has data member m_oMyClass of type MyClass

```
MyClass m_oMyClass;
```

then the constructor of class Foo at first calls the default constructor of class MyClass

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
  printf("constructor() called\n");
}
```

to create data member m_oMyClass before passing the control to its body.
Inside the body of the constructor of class Foo there is used the copy assignment operator to reassign object m_oMyClass.

```
  m_oMyClass = oMyClass;
```

You cou;d define the constructor of class Foo the following way

```
Foo::Foo( MyClass& oMyClass) :  m_oMyClass( oMyClass )
{
}
```

In this case instead of the default constructor and the copy assignment operator of class MyClass there would be called only copy constructor of class MyClass.

Answer (score 0):

The private "MyClass" object in your Foo class is being default constructed because you are not initializing it properly through a member initializer list.

There are a couple of solutions here, depending on what you want to achieve. You can initialize it with a copy constructor in the initialization list, or you can declare it as being a reference to a MyClass object.

For a more through explanation, please check http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list